# Golang os.Open can I use form file along with it for dynamic files

Tags: go

This is my first time using Os.Open and I was wondering can I use that for dynamic images (Images found in different directories) or do I have to put the full path every single time ? For instance in my FormFile

```
func ExampleFunc(w http.ResponseWriter, t *http.Request) {
     t.ParseForm()
     f, h, err := t.FormFile("file")
       if err != nil {
        print(err) }
       os.Open(h.Filename)
}
```

The function above gives me an error no such file or directory found however if I put the full path in there such as

```
os.Open("/Home/myfiles/Documents/pictures/horse_riding.png")
```

Then the image opens, is there a way of dynamically get the Image path and inserting that in os.Open ? I do have a FormFile that gets information about the incoming file but not the full path .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a file server (such as [this one](https://gist.github.com/alexisrobert/982674#file-webserver-go-L244)), you are suppose to concatenate a `root_folder` to the file/path you get from your form.

```
filepath := path.Join((root_folder), h.Filename)
```

That way, you open files which are within a certain root folder, instead of *any* file on your system (which is not secure at all).

Comment: Beware though that the `path` package is for manipulating path components of URIs; for filesystem paths one has to use the `path/filepath` package instead.